# Select data from table 1 and insert related data to second table 2 fields

Tags: sql

```
Leader Partner Ticket
    12      13 121969
    12      13 121962
    12      13 121897
    12      13 121782
    12      13 121774
    12      13 121172
    12      13 121970
    12      13 121975
    12      13 121971
    12      13 121976
```

I'm using this query, but it is not showing related record in the leader and partner field. I want to display leader and partner name from staffslist table.

```
SELECT performance.Leader, performance.Partner, performance.Ticket, performance.TaskType, performance.Status, staffslist.Shortname 
FROM performance 
INNER JOIN performance.Partner ON performance.Partner=staffslist.ID
```

Comment: i want display leader & Partner name from staffslist table .

Comment: Don't add more info to your question as comments, update your question instead by [editiing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58763368/edit) it.

Comment: I suppose you mean `INNER JOIN staffslist` instead of `INNER JOIN performance.Partner`

Comment: Please provide description and contents of stafflists table

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query isn't working (invalid `JOIN`). You can use the following instead:

```
SELECT stafflistL.Shortname AS Leader, stafflistP.Shortname AS Partner, performance.Ticket, performance.TaskType, performance.Status 
FROM performance 
  INNER JOIN stafflist stafflistL ON performance.Leader = staffslistL.ID 
  INNER JOIN stafflist stafflistP ON performance.Partner = staffslistP.ID
```

Comment: how can i use this query to update data using this code